# How to use faker gem in Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I have a faker gem installed (I made sure it was not inside dev/test!). I wanted to generate several random quotes on view. I want to put it inside welcome/index.

Inside my welcome_controller, I have:

```
require 'faker'

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @faker_array = []
    5.times do |n|
      @faker_array.push(Faker::HitchhikersGuideToTheGalaxy.quote)
    end
  end
```

I tried calling it but it gives me `"#<NameError: uninitialized constant Faker...` error.

```
  <% @faker_array.each do |el| %>
    <li><%= el %></li>
  <% end %>
```

I have also tried creating a service named `list_generator.rb`

```
require 'faker'

class ListGenerator
  def faker_hitchhiker_quote
    return Faker::HitchhikersGuideToTheGalaxy.quote
  end
end
```

And called the service inside the welcome index view, something like:

```
<ul>
  <% 5.times do |el| %>
    <li><%= ListGenerator.new.faker_hitchhiker_quote %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Doing that still gives me `#<NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::...` error.

Is there a way where I can integrate Faker gem inside my views to generate random quotes?

Comment: That looks like it should work, have you restarted the server after adding and bundling faker?

Answer (score 0):

According to the readme:

> Note: if you are getting a uninitialized constant Faker::[some_class] error, your version of the gem is behind the one documented here. To make sure that your gem is the one documented here, change the line in your gemfile to:

```
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Try this approach.